# Login challenge missing after migrating asp website from .net 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I'm upgrading an old internal website from .net 2 to 4 using [this procedure from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx).
I mostly got rid of .net assembly references in the web.config and switched the DefaultAppPool. However when I tried to access the website  using http://localhost/ the login challenge didn't show up.  `Request.LogonUserIdentity` Is being used to get credentials.

When I use http: //localhost/auth.aspx  the Challenge *does* come up. IIS manager has the auth.apx page set as default and I know for a fact it's being used, but the authentication doesn't show up unless I directly address it.

Any ideas as to why it would only work when i type the full address? (If i go back to using .net 2.0 the request shows up without the full address, it only seems to happen on 4.0)

did `Request.LogonUserIdentity` change from 2.0 to 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out IIS 7 doesn't allow an ASPX page to be the default page, which sorta makes sense to me . What I did was make IIS default page point to a blank html page that did a Javascript redirect to the aspx page and it started working

Answer (score 0):

See if it has anything to do with ASP.Net 4's [extensionless urls](http://forums.asp.net/t/1681675.aspx/1) feature.